# Placing Unique_Ptr in header creates reference to deleted function error?

Tags: c++, netbeans, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to use G3Log as my logger but I've come into a strange issue. When I do the recommended way of:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<g3::LogWorker> logWorker = { g3::LogWorker::createLogWorker() };
    auto sinkHandle = logWorker->addSink(...);
    g3::initializeLogging(logWorker.get());
}
```

It works as expected. Both in Netbeans 8.1 C/C++ and also Visual Studio 2017. However, when I do the following:

```
 class Log {
     std::unique_ptr<g3::LogWorker> mp_LogWorker;

     ...

     ...
 };

 Log::Log() :
 mp_LogWorker(g3::LogWorker::createLogWorker()) {
 ...
 // Essentially the same as the main above here.
 ...
 };
```

It works in Netbeans 8.1 in Linux, but upon attempting this same thing in VS2017, I get the following error:

```
error C2280: 'PE(const PE &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
note: 'Log(const Log &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::unique_ptr<g3::LogWorker, ...>
```

Now upon trying to research this error, google comes up with the fact that a unique_ptr is not copyable, otherwise it wouldn't be unique. I understand this, but it seems to work on Linux fine in Netbeans 8.1, but it doesn't work in VS2017.

Any ideas why this might be? I'm yet to try this on MacOS, but I've a feeling this may not work on that either due to my Macbook running VS2017 too.

EDIT:

I thought PE may have been the culprit, but it does not copy anything, just instantiates:

```
class PE {
private:
    Log m_Log;

public:
    PE();
};

PE::PE() :
m_Log() {

};
```

And, as I previously said, this worked fine in Netbeans 8.1 Linux?

Comment: Have you read documentation about unique_ptr?

Comment: Remove the `=` in `...logworker = {...};`, so it is an _initialization_, and not a _copy_.

Comment: The error is in code you are not showing. You error message seems to say that you are trying to copy a `PE` class-instance, that in turn contains, hence tries to copy, a `Log` class-instance.
If you need really need to copy a PE/Log you need define a copy-constructor that moves the unique_ptr. Or just avoid copying PE/Log if possible.